# How to copy locked file on windows in rust?

Tags: windows, rust

I want to copy locked file, but got error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. File locking on POSIX is advisory (opt-in), but on Windows it is enforced by the operating system. If another process has a file open and asked for exclusive access, you need that process to close the file, or you need to kill that process.

Comment: You can try using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which may allow you to bypass file locking in the Windows subsystem.  It may or may not work, but it's more likely to work than with a Windows process.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that you don't have the permission right to read from your file. Eg. even if `foo.txt` is changed and left open in a program, it is still possible to copy the file contents to `bar.txt` with `std::fs::copy("foo.txt", "bar.txt");` on Windows 11.

Comment: @Kaplan, I'm the only admin, i think it's not a permission problem.

Comment: Use the `attrib` command to check if the file has any flag set that prevents the access, such as eg. the `hidden` flag `H`.